# How to get multiple tables from stored procedure in RDLC?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, rdlc

Got a massive issues with understanding .rdlc reports.

My situation is:
I have a procedure with incoming parameters, but with multiple select results.
When I tried to add it with dataset, nothing happened, but any other procedure (where result is only one select) working as intended (it appears in "available datasets".

As I understand, it is possible to create DataSet by my own and send inside .rdlc form, somehow, but I can't get it at all (for example, how I supposed to Design .rdlc after this).

Right now I received 4 Lists with data from Stored Procedure, and I need to send those inside .rdlc. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try to break up the stored procedure into 4 parts, and then add each one as a separate dataset in the RDLC.

Answer (score 0):

By default the report wizard will only take the first result set of a stored proc. You *can* handle multiple result sets from a stored proc in a .rdlc generated programmatically within an ASP.NET WebForms application, but it's not simple... at least the way I know how to do it isn't. Take for example the following proc that returns 3 result sets:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Multipass
AS
    DECLARE @t table (ID int, SomeText varchar(256));
    SELECT ID AS FirstID, SomeText AS FirstName FROM @t;
    SELECT ID AS SecondID, SomeText AS SecondName FROM @t;
    SELECT ID AS ThirdID, SomeText AS ThirdName FROM @t;
    RETURN 0;
```

Now you'll have to add your datasets manually to the report file. Create a blank Report item and open in a text editor (in Visual Studio you can right-click the .rdlc file, click Open With... and select Xml Editor for pretty colors.) The full XML of the .rdlc with the datasets for the above stored proc added would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Width>6.5in</Width>
  <Body>
    <Height>2in</Height>
  </Body>
  <rd:ReportTemplate>true</rd:ReportTemplate>
  <Page>
  </Page>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="Whatever">
      <DataSourceReference>Whatever</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:DataSourceID>b257dc38-aff2-4fac-9e8b-73ea232f5ca8</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet0">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="FirstID">
          <DataField>FirstID</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.int</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="FirstName">
          <DataField>FirstName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.string</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>Whatever</DataSourceName>
        <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
        <CommandText>dbo_multipass</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="SecondID">
          <DataField>SecondID</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.int</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="SecondName">
          <DataField>SecondName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.string</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>Whatever</DataSourceName>
        <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
        <CommandText>dbo_multipass</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet2">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="ThirdID">
          <DataField>ThirdID</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.int</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="ThirdName">
          <DataField>ThirdName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.string</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>Whatever</DataSourceName>
        <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
        <CommandText>Multipass</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
</Report>
```

Note that I named each dataset with a number after it, that's important in the code that uses the template to generate the report. Do something like the following that will loop through the collection of resultsets from the stored proc and add them to the report for rendering:

```
private byte[] GetReport()
{
    Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] warnings = null;
    string[] streamids = null;
    string mimeType = null;
    string encoding = null;
    string extension = null;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try
    {
        //  Retrieve the dataset from your stored proc which will contain a DataTable object for each resultset
        DataSet ds = this.GetMultipass();

        //  Instantiate a report object using your new spiffy template
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport rpt = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport();
        rpt.ReportPath = "path_to_your_report.rdlc";
        rpt.DataSources.Clear();

        //  Now we loop through the tables and add them as ReportDataSource objects to the LocalReport object
        for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            //  Note that we name each datasource DataSet0, DataSet1, DataSet2 to match the DataSet names in the .rdlc. Kinda important.
            rpt.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource($"DataSet{(i > 0 ? i.ToString() : "")}", ds.Tables[i]));
        }

        // Adjust the render to how you want the output
        bytes = rpt.Render("EXCELOPENXML", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //  Blame the internet for misguiding you
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

There is possibly a better way to do this, and hopefully there's a way to do this without WebForms or I'm in trouble when I finally migrate my application to MVC. Anyway, I hope this helps guide you in a functional direction!